# Who is "community wiki Charles?"

Tags: discussion, support

Who is *community wiki [Charles](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/17503/charles)* who posted [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35233/what-is-the-biblical-argument-that-homosexual-attraction-is-sinful-by-itself/35306#35306) to [What is the Biblical argument that homosexual attraction is sinful by itself?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35233/what-is-the-biblical-argument-that-homosexual-attraction-is-sinful-by-itself)

1. I guess I am not clear about the *community wiki* part.
2. I am having a difficulty understanding why his "answer" is at +1/0 votes when [the comment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35233/what-is-the-biblical-argument-that-homosexual-attraction-is-sinful-by-itself/35306#comment95011_35306) by @fredsbend below it indicates it's not an answer.

---

**Update 1:** @fredsbend's comment has now disappeared. *Why?* See image capture below.

[image]

**Update 2:** "Community wiki Charles" is now just "Charles." *What happened?*

Comment: I think in general you attach more significance to vote counts than is warranted. In this case, *one* person upvoted the answer and nobody else did anything.

Comment: I remember that this was a community wiki post at first (Ward linked to where to learn about that). I don't know how that's been undone. I'm not sure why my comment was deleted. I think it was still current and constructive. Oh, well. No big deal to me.

Comment: @fredsbend Thank you for weighing in here. That's that was the purpose of bullet point 1. that does not appear to have  registered with Mr.Bultitude. I made this post because of noticing what to me was an unusual post, and trying to understand it. And now I have updated the post to try to understand why "community wiki" has now disappeared from "Charles".

Comment: The post in question had no business being marked as a Community Wiki post. It was not produced through a collaborative effort and marking it as such for a year attracted no activity. There was no point it such a marking so I removed it and made it a normal post again. Look at the edit history for the post to answer these kinds of questions. It will show how it changed at when.

Comment: @Caleb Thank you Caleb for the clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overall questions about how SE works are usually found on meta.SE.  e.g. [All about Community Wiki posts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: I appreciate your post and the education.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: Selected after Caleb's clarifying comment.

Answer (score 1):

"Charles" is the name of the member who made the first post.

The "community wiki" part means that anybody including folks without any rep at all can edit post on this site. The point of CW posts is not to lower the bar but to relinquish ownership to encourage more collaboration. For the most part, it is a useless feature for this site.